# "Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject" when changing SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an error "Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject" in my project.

My comment is used to load a file and create a list. This list is bind to a ListBox. AL was working good. But I created a Task to load (load can be long). Now I have this error. I don't understand why it occurs.

There is my code :

MainView.xaml:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Results}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <ListBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}"
                    Key="Delete"/>
    </ListBox.InputBindings>
</ListBox>

<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"                    
        Style="{StaticResource StyleButton}"
        Command="{Binding LoadCommand}"
        Content="Open result"/>
```

MainViewModel:

```
#region Fields/Properties
public ImageWithPoints SelectedItem
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedItem;
    }
    set
    {
        _selectedItem = value;
        SelectedPointIndex = 1;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        OnPropertyChanged("Picture");
        UpdatePoints();
    }
}
        public List<ImageWithPoints> Results
{
    get
    {
        return _results;
    }
    set
    {
        _results = value;
        if (value == null)
        {
            SelectedPointIndex = 0;
        }
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
public BitmapSource Picture
{
    get
    {
        return SelectedItem?.Picture;
    }
}
#endregion
#region Load
private ICommand _loadCommand;
public ICommand LoadCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_loadCommand == null)
            _loadCommand = new RelayCommand(OnLoad, CanLoad);
        return _loadCommand;
    }
}
public void OnLoad()
{
    StartRunning(this, null);
    Task loadTask = new Task(new Action(() =>
    {
        Load();
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            StopRunning(this, null);
        }));
    }));
    loadTask.Start();
}
public bool CanLoad()
{
    return !IsRunning;
}
#endregion
#region Events  
public event EventHandler OnStartRunning;
public event EventHandler OnStopRunning;
private void StartRunning(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnStartRunning(sender, e);
}
private void StopRunning(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnStopRunning(sender, e);
}
#enregion
#region Methods
public void Load()
{
    // Open File
    // Set to list
    List<ImageWithPoints> listRes;
    Results = listRes;
    SelectedItem = Results[0];  
}
#endregion
```

When I remove the line `SelectedItem = Results[0];` I have no error (but application don't work has it should).

Comment: You should have that line inside the Dispatcher Action.

Comment: I modified to `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>{SelectedItem = Results[0];}));` but I still have the error.

Comment: But you didn't try to put the whole `Load` code into the Dispatcher Action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the SelectedItem property back on the UI thread once the Task has finished:

```
public void OnLoad()
{
    StartRunning(this, null);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(() =>
    {
        Load();
    })).ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        SelectedItem = Results[0];
        StopRunning(this, null);
    }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

You can only access a UI element on the thread on which it was originally created so if your `UpdatePoints()` method accesses any control you *must* call this method on the UI thread.